# Backbone with websockets (sockjs) (changing Backbone.ajax vs Backbone.sync)

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, websocket, marionette, sockjs

I have a confusion -
If I am implementing `websockets (sockjs)` on top of `Backbone` and `Marionette`, then, in my opinion, it should only require a change in `Backbone.ajax` function so that `socket.emit` and `socket.on` are supported in place of `model.save (or collection.save)` and `model.fetch (or collection.fetch)`. 

 
However, when I did some research and I found that this was not the case. I came across - 
 1. Derick Bailey's article: 
 https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/19/decoupling-backbone-apps-from-websockets/ 
 which doesn't even talk about changing `Backbone.ajax` or `Backbone.sync`, instead it suggests event aggregation - which is a part of the solution of using websockets but misses the whole point of syncing models and collections. Ok, it does talk about `backbone.iobind` but only mentions it as an "alternative" approach to event aggregation (however, this is only my reading of the article, I might have missed something!). 
 
 2. And Christopher Keefer's article: 
 http://artandlogic.com/2014/06/websockets-for-backbone/ 
 It does exactly what I want (on socket.io) but it does the job by changing parts of `Backbone.sync` except `Backbone.ajax`!

 
My question is whether Backbone can work for sockjs just by changing its `Backbone.ajax` function?

Comment: I guess someone poisoned Derick Bailey with events. I really don't like the `vent` thingy he uses in many articles. It feels like a hack. Just my opinion thoguh

Comment: I find `vent` thingy used by Derick Bailey as a very clean way of separating distinct parts of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your persistence methods, you should override `Backbone.sync`

### [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

> You can override it in order to use a different persistence strategy, such as **WebSockets**, XML transport, or Local Storage.

(*emphasis mine*)

`Backbone.sync` is your gateway to persistence layer. By default this is handled using AJAX, and in most cases uses jQuery AJAX.

---

### [`Backbone.ajax`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-ajax)

> If you want to use a **custom AJAX function**, or your endpoint doesn't support the jQuery.ajax API and you need to tweak things, you can do so by setting Backbone.ajax.

(*emphasis mine*)

`Backbone.ajax` is just a proxy to jQuery AJAX:

```
Backbone.ajax = function() {
  return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
}
```

The docs clearly says when you would want to override `Backbone.ajax`. Another unrealistic example would be when you're using another DOM manipulation library in place of jQuery which doesn't have built in AJAX support exposed using an `ajax` method.

---

`Backbone.sync` method contains code that assumes you're using AJAX (it manipulates an `xhr` object). That's what you should override.
Using `ajax` method to do something that isn't ajax doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Another possible way to use websockets in backbone is to change models inside socket.on... function and then do a collection.set on the changed model!